# switch namespace by if condtion

Tags: c++, namespaces, if-statement

in my C++ program I have several namespaces that contain several pointers with identical names.
I then want a function to choose a namespace according to a parameter. I.e. something like:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace ns1{
double x[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
}
namespace ns2{
double x[5]={6,7,8,9,10};
}

int main(){
  int b=1;
  if(b==1){
    using namespace ns1;
  }
  if(b==2){
    using namespace ns2;
  }
  std::cout << x[3] << std::endl;
}
```

However, this doesn't work since the compiler complains that x isn't known in that scope. I guess the problem is that "using namespace ..." is only valid within the if-statement.
I think that it should be possible to switch namespaces somehow, but cannot find out how...
Do you know how to do this without casting all variable separately?

```
int main(){
  int b=1;
  double *x;
  if(b==1){
    x = ns1::x;
  }
  if(b==2){
    x = ns2::x;
  }
  std::cout << x[3] << std::endl;
}
```

Cheers,
Pascal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Namespaces are a compile-time feature in C++, you can't manipulate them dynamically in runtime. The best advice I could give you is try a different approach - namespaces are probably not meant to do what you want to do. So ask SO what you *really* want to do and you'll likely get a good answer without bending the system.

Comment: ah, I didn't know that. So, defining a class that contains everything contained in a workspace and casting that would be the most elegant way?

Comment: @user575873: probably not, although it may work. This just doesn't sound right - why you need a namespace if you're going to wrap it all in a class anyway?. Again, I suggest you open a new question and explain exactly what you're trying to achieve in it.

Comment: You were right. I figured out that classes suit my problem much better.

Comment: The problem basically was to store parameters (Gauss-Kronrod abscissa used in a numerical integration) so that the function (doing the integration) chooses the right parameter set according to the chosen number of integration points. I made a more simple example, because I felt that the math might confuse some people.

Comment: @pascal: then namespaces are not the solution here at all for encapsulating the parameters. Why not just return a vector of parameters from a function, and call the right function for some number of integration points?

Comment: now, I've got a class doing the job. For each number of integration points there's a class containing the necessary parameter set - so basically as CashCow suggested.
Is there any advantage of doing it with a function instead of classes?

Comment: @pascal: it depends on many factors - complexity, need for state, need to hide stuff inside the class. In general my advice is go for the simplest approach that works for you (and be ready to refactor later if needed). For a more comprehensive discussion you may need to open a separate question and formulate exactly what you want to know

Answer (score 1):

The namespace is used at compilation time. The if state ist executed at run time.

You can't switch the compiler behavior at run time.

Answer (score 1):

I fail to see why you don't want this:

```
double* dispatch(int b)
{
    switch(b)
    {
        case 1: return ns1::x;
        case 2: return ns2::x;
        default: return 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int b=1;
    std::cout << dispatch(b)[3] << std::endl;
}
```

If this is going to grow, consider using classes and polymorphism instead of namespaces.

Comment: In my real program I have more than one variable per namespace. In that case you'd also need more than one dispatch function...

Comment: @pascal: so why don't you use classes and virtual dispatch then ?

Comment: I could of course that. But then you would again end up wrapping the whole namespace into a class - and then you don't need the namespace in the first place...

Comment: @pascal: You don't need the namespace in the first place. Namespaces are not classes. You want classes, not namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest state you have "static" data but want to decide which piece of static data to use.

```
struct space
{
  double x[5];
};

space space1 = space{ {1,2,3,4,5} };
space space2 = space{ {6,7,8,9,10} };

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
   space * s;
   if( argc == 1 )
       s = &space1;
   else
       s = &space2;
}
```

In reality of course your spaces will more than just one member and you will populate them in a different manner but it is one way you can chose which instance you use.

You might use polymorphism to implement functions but it depends a lot on what you need it for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe namespaces are something that is determined during run time... therefore you won't be able to set it up as such.

A quick google of "changing namespace at runtime" returned http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t288720-changing-namespace-at-runtime.html

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

the `using namespace` directives basically is telling the compiler to "try to use this when resolving symbols", which doesn't happen at runtime.

I don't see any problem with the second approach....

Comment: well, if you have many variables in each namespace, it's a bit troublesome to write...

Comment: well you need better way to manage those variables, perhaps a struct or class then.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before it won't work... I would suggest that you use polymorphism if you have many variables that you want to put in your container class to achieve the intended result:

```
// Header file
class s
{
  public:
    double x[5];
}

class s1: public s 
{
  public:
    s1() { /* Assign x here */ };        
}

class s2: public s
{
  public:
    s2() { /* Assign x here */ };
}

// CPP file
int main()
{
  int b = 1;
  s* sptr;

  if (b == 1)
    sptr = (s*)new s1();
  else
    sptr = (s*)new s2();

  std::cout << sptr->x[3] << std::endl;
  delete sptr;
}
```

If you only have a few variables you could use pointers.

```
int main()
{
  int b = 1;
  double *px;
  double s1x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  double s2x = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

  if (b == 1)
    px = &s1x;
  else
    px = &s2x;

  std::cout << px[3] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Just wondering: Why do you have to use polymorphism? Can't you just define a class s and then define s1 and s2 as const s ?

Comment: You don't have to use polymorphism. It depends on how complex your implementation is. If you have many common variables with different values polymorphism is a good option, but if you only have 1 variable (x) there are much easier ways to implement the solution (refer to CashCow's answer).